# How do I loop through an Excel Pivot Slicer for each member of the slicer while saving the results of a sheet on another sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to loop through 1 slicer for all the items I want to capture a value from one cell and paste it on another sheet (while also capturing the slicer item name). Please help, I know I need a loop but can't get anything to work

Sub CtryFilter2()

```
Dim sC As slicerCache
Dim sI As slicerItem
Dim sIDummy As slicerItem
Dim i As Long
Dim l As Long

'application.ScreenUpdating=false

'Assign slicer to variable
Set sC = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_CTRY_DESC")

'Initiate loop through each country in the slicer
sC.PivotTables(1).ManualUpdate = True
'sC.ClearManualFilter

With sC
For i = 1 To sC.SlicerCacheLevels.Count

    For Each sI In sC.SlicerCacheLevels(i).SlicerItems

    If i = 1 Then Sheets.Add.Name = sC.Name Else

        Sheets("Graph").Range("C2:R2").Copy
        Sheets(sC.Name).Range("b" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    End
        'sC.ClearManualFilter

        'Create new tab and rename based on current selection
        'Sheets.Add.Name = sI.Value
        'Copy paste values from POS_DETAIL tab to the new tab
        Sheets("Graph").Range("C2:R2").Copy
        Sheets(sC.Name).Range("b" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next sI
```

Next i
    End With
    'Garbage Collection
    Set sC = Nothing
End Sub

Comment: anything you tried that you could show?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Added code to the above